# rails 3.1, how to add custom condition to after_filter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

How can I add a custom condition for `after_filter` or `before_filter`

How can I have something like this:

```
after_filter :handle_student_time_tracking, :condition=> ( !current_student.nil? )
```

I can put the condition inside handle_student_time_tracking but, I think there is a better way
Please advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the conditions in your filter, not on the after_filter call. Like this:

```
after_filter :handle_student_time_tracking

def handle_student_time_tracking
  raise "I'm in an after filter!" if current_student.present?
end
```

The conditions that filters provide are for actions, like `only` and `except`, not based on other conditions.

Reference:

- http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html

Comment: @simo this seems to not be true: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4f940820f29f8fc9c9113baca709aae11683b596/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb#L28 you should be able to use `:if`